# wxPython wx.FileDialog takes time to load

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm building an application with wxPython and I need to ask the user for a file. here are my functions:

```
def choose_path(self, event):
    """Choose the path"""
    self.btnPath.Disable()
    path, exists = open_file()
    self.btnPath.Enable()
    if path is not None:
        if exists:
            self.txtPath.SetLabel(path)

    self.btnOpen.Enable(bool(self.txtPath.GetValue()))


def open_file(default_path="data\\pcap"):
    """Method for opening files,returns the file_path of the choosen file and exists"""

    file_path = None
    dialog = wx.FileDialog(None, "File Browser", default_path,
                           style=wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_MULTIPLE | wx.STAY_ON_TOP, wildcard=OPEN_WILDCARD)

    if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        file_path = dialog.GetPath()

    dialog.Destroy()

    return file_path, os.path.exists(file_path)
```

The problem is that sometimes it takes time to load the FileDialog and the application crashes. what can I do about it?

Comment: Does the path you want to show have lots and lots of files/dirs?  What error do you get when the application crashes, any traceback?

Comment: No, it crashes without traceback, it freezes for second or two then says python.exe is not responding

Comment: And it does not start responding after some time?

Comment: If I don't touch it, it does. but if I only move the window it crashes. The problem is it takes time to load the FileDialog. Also I open the FileDialog from another Dialog

Comment: Hhm, could you do a stand alone example which shows the problem, so one can experiment with it?